# Python- How to open two excel files with each in its own excel application

Tags: python, excel, win32com

How can you open an xlsx file in a separate excel application then a second xls file, so that during a condition, I just want to close one of them and not both.  The current code below, opens both files in the same excel application even though I am opening specifying two separate excel objects.  And when call the close() function on one of the files, it closes both. My requirement is that I have to do his with dispatch from win32com.  Thanks.

```
import time, os.path, os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

path1 = 'C:\\Todolist.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:\\Todolist2.xlsx'

xla = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xla.DisplayAlerts = False
xla.Visible = True

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Visible = True

wb1=xla.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path1)
wb2= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path2)

time.sleep(3)

wbCloseA = xla.Workbooks.Close()
```

Comment: try this: ["instead of using `.Dispatch`, use `.DispatchEx` to start the application."](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/start-a-new-com-instance.html)

Comment: Use (eg) `wb1.Close()` if you only want to close a specific workbook

Comment: @davedwards Thanks that worked.  Workbook closed but the excel application remains open.  I dont need it closed but just for future reference, whats the function to close file and excel app?

Comment: @TimWilliams wb1.Close() works too thanks!

Comment: `xla.Quit()` would close the Excel instance

Comment: @Tim Williams thanks that worked